# How to read a topic model trained in command line into a Java class?

Tags: java, lda, topic-modeling, mallet

So I've a trained model that was created through command line with MALLET. I want to, somehow, import this trained model into a Java class. I looked through MALLET's API documentation and came across their `ParallelTopicModel` class but couldn't find a suitable way to import the model as a `ParallelTopicModel` which is what I want to do.

I know that it's possible to train a model using the MALLET Java API inside the Java class itself but I do not want to do this.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If that trained model generated both the **data model** and the **data instances** you can do this. The `ParallelTopicModel` will use the data model and the `Pipe` that it used to train the model will be used to create an `InstanceList`, which you will need for the `TopicInferencer`.

```
String testingText = "my test";
ParallelTopicModel model = ParallelTopicModel.read(new File("data_model_path"));
InstanceList instances = InstanceList.load(new File("data_instances_path"));

// Create a new instance with the testing text
InstanceList testing = new InstanceList(instances.getPipe());
testing.addThruPipe(new Instance(testing_text, null, "Test Instance", null));

// Create the inferencer
TopicInferencer inferencer = model.getInferencer();
```